# Looking for a way to convert a 3D model I found online into an LDD model (or related software)

Tags: design, ldd, bricklink

I was recently viewing bricklink.com's user gallery and I found [a design](https://www.bricklink.com/r3/studio/design.page?idModel=227674) that I would like to recreate. I know the exact pieces that I need for the design (about 5000), but there are no detailed instructions on how to build it and the only thing available to me is a 3D blueprint of the design provided by the author. I tried contacting the designer for the LDD file but was unsuccessful. Since I know the exact pieces, Is it possible to somehow translate the online blueprint into LDD or a related software?

Comment: I can't offer a way to do what you ask for, just a word of warning: the model is ~112 studs long (give or take a few), which translates to around 90 cm, which is 50% larger than the biggest official LEGO sets ever released: [UCS Millennium Falcon](http://brickset.com/sets/10179), [Hogwarts Castle](http://brickset.com/sets/71043) or [Taj Mahal](http://brickset.com/sets/10256) - moving or even displaying this beast would be an enormous challenge, not to speak of dusting it.

Comment: @zovits the description on the linked page says *"Size: 90x33x41cm"* and *"it's very heavy and should be exhibited without any other purpose"* so I think we can safely assume OP already knows that.

Comment: @zovits The [Imperial Star Destroyer](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/product/imperial-star-destroyer-75252) measures 110x66x37cm (without its stand), so this is comparable to that.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid thanks for the heads-up, apparently I misunderstood the "dimensions" row of Brickset as the dimensions of the model, whereas they are of the packaging instead.

Answer (score 4):

The design is created in Stud.io (as all designs on Studio Gallery) and the creator has explicitly chosen to not make his .io file available.
So in trying to recreate this, you would go against the authors wishes, basically committing a copyright violation.

If you could somehow persuade the author to give you the .io file, than you could theoretically export it to .ldr file format (LDRAW file) from Stud.io and import it back into LDD. However for a model of this size and complexity, there would be guaranteed some complications and issues you need to resolve manually... Also bare in mind that LDD is no longer maintained or supported while Stud.io is. The latter has also a much richer feature set, e.g. the ability to order the necessary bricks from bricklink.